# Custom border in MonoTouch Dialog Section

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

What is the best way to customize the border in a Section? Nic Wise wrote a [great article](http://fastchicken.co.nz/2012/05/20/earnest-debrief-visual-styles-in-ios-apps-uiappearence-custom-sections-in-monotouch-dialog/) on customizing MT.D where he changes the border to a nice not-so-round version, but this involves modifying the MT.D code.

Is there a way to customize this using the standard MT.D?

I'm happy with only supporting iOS 5 (if the Appearance API could help).